# How to keep items I enter into a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Each time I enter a restaurant name and then go to print the list, it does not stay inside that list. I also need to be able to use the randomize command so that Randomize() will generate a random number and use it as an index to print the restaurant at that index to the screen.

```
while(True):
  getInput=input("Enter a restaurant name: ")
  list=[]
  list.append(getInput)
  if(str(getInput) == "List"):
    print(list)
  elif(str(getInput) == "Quit"):
    break;
```

I end up getting this:
Enter a restaurant name: Name
Enter a restaurant name: Names
Enter a restaurant name: List
['List']
Enter a restaurant name:

I need to be able to enter a restaurant and then be able to pull up that certain restaurant with a number. I just started Python a couple of months ago. Thank you!

Comment: Note how often `list=[]` is being run.

Comment: and no need to convert to string something which is already a string

Comment: You are creating a new list each time the loop repeats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things: 
You don't want to use a name like "list" because it's a function and type in Python which can make things confusing so instead name it something like "my_list".

And your issue was every loop you were starting the list from scratch. You want to move that list outside the loop instead.

```py
my_list = []
while True:
    getInput = input("Enter a restaurant name: ")
    my_list.append(getInput)
    if getInput == "List":
        print(my_list)
    elif getInput == "Quit":
        break
```

---

Edit:

To answer your comment question, you can add in a number using a manual counter if you wanted (for simplicity and understandability):

```py
my_list = []
id = 0
while True:
    getInput = input("Enter a restaurant name: ")
    my_list.append(f'{id}_{getInput}')
    id += 1
    if getInput == "List":
        print(my_list)
    elif getInput == "Quit":
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about assigning each restaurant a number? I know about the random command into that? Would it go before the loop?

Comment: @TiaSaurusRex I added a way to append the number to the restaurant name. If you didn't want to do it like that then you would need to use a different type of storage like a dictionary maybe or a tuple to store multiple things per restaurant. Please click the checkmark on my answer if it answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new list each time the loop repeats. Instead you should create the list before the loop even starts.